# how to start a telegram bot on heroku?

Tags: python, heroku, telegram, python-telegram-bot

**Context:**
I am trying to deploy and run a telegram bot on heroku. I am using Python 3.11.2 and the library python-telegram-bot==20.2. I want to deploy my bot on heroku but after that the bot doesn't respond to any action in Telegram.

**Question:** How to fix the problem?

**Code:**

1. send_news_to_channel.py

```
from telegram import ReplyKeyboardMarkup
from telegram.ext import Application, ContextTypes, CommandHandler
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import os
from telegram import Update
from get_news_from_reddit import get_most_popul_post_today
load_dotenv()

PORT = int(os.environ.get('PORT', 5000))


async def say_hi(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE) -> None:
    await update.message.reply_text('Hi! I am Reddit news bot!')


async def wake_up(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE) -> None:
    button = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(
        [['/most_popular_post']], resize_keyboard=True
    )
    await update.message.reply_text('Thanks for turning me on!', reply_markup=button)


async def send_reddit_post(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE) -> None:
    await update.message.reply_text(get_most_popul_post_today())


def main():
    token = os.getenv("TG_BOT_TOKEN")
    application = Application.builder().token(token).build()
    application.add_handler(CommandHandler("most_popular_post", send_reddit_post))
    application.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", wake_up))
    #application.run_polling()
    application.start_webhook(
        listen="0.0.0.0",
        port=int(PORT),
        url_path=token,

    )
    application.bot.setWebhook('https://safe-chamber-19168.herokuapp.com/' + token)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

2. Procfile

`web: python3 get_news_from_reddit.py`

3. how to deploy on Heroku

```
git add .
git commit -m 'change send news to heroku' 
git push heroku master                     
heroku ps:scale web=1
```